# How do I hide .asmx webservice API endpoint in source code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am calling .asmx service from inside script tag in aspx page. When I view the page source it's showing my webservice.

How to protect the webservice from expose?
cause when some one view the page source then he can see the web service name as well as its all methods name.

.aspx Page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="divBody" runat="server">
        <div class="aa-dashboard-wrapper">
            <asp:Textbox id="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:Textbox> 
        </div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Here is my script tag, that is placed at the bottom of my aspx page.

```
    $("#textbox1").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/webServiceMethod") %>',
                        data: "{ 'keyword': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        timeout: 20000,
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                        },
                        error: function (response) {

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {

                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {

                },
                minLength: 2
            })

</script>
```

Comment: The web service is being called from the user's browser with an ajax request, if it is not publicly exposed, how do you expect it to work?

Comment: can i encode its name?
by this he might not see the asmx service name ?

Comment: Ultimately the user's browser is making an http request to your web service, even if you obfuscated the end point all a user has to do is fire up the browsers dev tools or use something like fiddler and they can see the requests.  What are you trying to hide? why does it matter that the user can see the endpoint of your web service?  If the user crafting their own calls to the service is a problem then you have a fundamental security issue with the web service.

Comment: If you give more details about what you are trying to secure and why I might be able to offer more useful advice.  There are steps you can take to make sure your web service is as secure as possible, e.g. you can store a security token in a cokkie and then check that security token against a known value, this helps secure against XSRF vulnerabilities by ensuring the request is made by the user on your website and not some other evil site :-)

Answer (score 4):

While you can't stop users from seeing the URL of your service, you can stop them viewing the documentation for it - just put this inside the `system.web` tag of your `web.config`

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <remove name="Documentation" />
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815149 on 'Removing the Documentation Protocol'

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have a JS file and place your AJAX call there. Even in this case, user can browse and view the JS, but the chances are little less.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to completely hide your API endpoints from someone who wants to find it. Even if you somehow obfuscate the calling of it in some javascript construction, it will still be visible in Chrome web inspector. And at the most basic level, I can still see it when I intercept the communication with packet sniffers.